# Push notification through java gives error?

Tags: java, ios, iphone, push-notification

I am using this code to send push notification to iphone:

```
String regId="device_token";
Push.alert(userMessage,http://domainname.com/iphone/development_certificate/new/Certificates.p12,"password",false,regId);
```

When I am sending that message using `Javaapns` it gives me the following error:

```
The exception is javapns.communication.exceptions.InvalidKeystoreReferenceException: Invalid keystore reference.  File does not exist: C:\Users\Java\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\GF_4.0\domain1\config\http://domainname.com/iphone/development_certificate/new/Certificates.p12
```

When I am giving `D:\\Certificates.p12` it is running fine but when i give online path of keystore then it is giving error.

Comment: The error is very clear, the path to you certificate is wrong. You can see in the error message that the URL is appended to the the config directory: `C:\Users\Java\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\GF_4.0\domain1\config\http://domainname.com/iphone/development_certificate/new/Certificates.p12` You will need to make sure the path to the certificate is correct,

Comment: @rckoenes I know that but I want to know how to correct that path.

Comment: You can only use local files, not online path.

Comment: @rckoenes  How can i use local files Could you plz tell me the syntax because i am sending this notification from my online site.